# Wildcard sub subdomin on github.io

Tags: github, subdomain, github-pages, wildcard-subdomain

GitHub pages gives every user a subdomain such as `https://user.github.io`.
A project can also be hosted on a sub-path such as `https://user.github.io/project`.
I wonder is it possible to have a sub subdomain on the `github.io` domain such as the form of `https://project.user.github.io`?.
I am not looking for how to configure self-owned custom domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You will need your own domain if you want something else.